# Where to get Android 4.4.0 since SDK Manager has 4.4.2

Tags: android, sdk

We need to write code to work around a bug in Android 4.4 which is later fixed in 4.4.2. How can we install the older image: 4.4 (not 4.4.2 or whatever is latest)?

Comment: see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just system image for checking the bug, you can pull the needed one for version 4.4 from the following sources:

1. [Android* 4.4 (KitKat) x86 Emulator System Image](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-4-4-kitkat-x86-emulator-system-image)
2. [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerheadkrt16m)
3. [android-x86](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list)